# How can I group the output from my MySQL Query, I want to sum the equipCost output by ID. ie I want the accountCost to be SUM'd by their account

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  
vAccountEquipCost.`accountID`,
vAccountEquipCost.`accountName`,
vAccountEquipCost.`accountNo`,
vAccountEquipCost.`woEquipCost` AS equipCost
FROM 
vAccountEquipCost

UNION ALL

SELECT 
vAccountExpenseCost.`accountID`,
vAccountExpenseCost.`accountName`,
vAccountExpenseCost.`accountNo`,
(vAccountExpenseCost.`acctTotal`) AS expCost
FROM 
vAccountExpenseCost

UNION ALL

SELECT 
vAccountLaborCost.`accountID`,
vAccountLaborCost.`accountName`,
vAccountLaborCost.`accountNo`,
vAccountLaborCost.`totalPay` AS laborcost
FROM
vAccountLaborCost

UNION ALL

SELECT 
vAccountMaterialCost.`accountID`,
vAccountMaterialCost.`accountName`,
vAccountMaterialCost.`accountNo`,
vAccountMaterialCost.`totalMaterialCost` AS materialCost
FROM
vAccountMaterialCost
```

[image]

Here is the code, what do I need to do to SUM for equipCost by accountID or accountNo? The views have some of the same tables like 'accounts', which are used to create the 'cost' for each account. The goal is to sum the output of each view. What am I missing in my logic? 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you have the accounts table if so please include in your question

Comment: Can you show an example of your required output.

Comment: If you want to sum then use sum function with group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to solved your problem, but based on what i understood to your question.. you should put an outer `select` as if

```
select accountID, accountName, accountNo, sum(cost) as cost from (
SELECT  
vAccountEquipCost.`accountID`,
vAccountEquipCost.`accountName`,
vAccountEquipCost.`accountNo`,
vAccountEquipCost.`woEquipCost` AS cost
FROM 
vAccountEquipCost

UNION ALL

SELECT 
vAccountExpenseCost.`accountID`,
vAccountExpenseCost.`accountName`,
vAccountExpenseCost.`accountNo`,
(vAccountExpenseCost.`acctTotal`) AS cost
FROM 
vAccountExpenseCost

UNION ALL

SELECT 
vAccountLaborCost.`accountID`,
vAccountLaborCost.`accountName`,
vAccountLaborCost.`accountNo`,
vAccountLaborCost.`totalPay` AS cost
FROM
vAccountLaborCost

UNION ALL

SELECT 
vAccountMaterialCost.`accountID`,
vAccountMaterialCost.`accountName`,
vAccountMaterialCost.`accountNo`,
vAccountMaterialCost.`totalMaterialCost` AS cost
FROM
vAccountMaterialCost ) as tbl
group by accountID
```

Comment: accountID" "accountName" "accountNo" "cost"
"1"                     "Water"            "53400" "2457.29"
"3"                     "Storm"            "53100" "696.96"
"4"                     "Streets"            "54200" "60"
"6"                     "Equipment" "53001"         "73.22999999999999"
"7"                     "Facilities"         "53002"         "48.35"
"8"                     "Services"         "54800"         "1660.28"